# Create new pandas df by referencing 2 existing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Been spinning my wheels over the most efficient way to accomplish the below, so looking for some guidance. For context, df1 shape is (599379,319). Thank you in advance.

df1:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| val 1 | val 1 |
| val 2 | val 2 |

df2:

| C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | val 1 | val 3 |
| A | val 2 | val 4 |
| B | val 1 | val 3 |
| B | val 2 | val 4 |

Desired Output:

| A | A1 | B | B1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| val 1 | val 3 | val 1 | val 3 |
| val 2 | val 4 | val 2 | val 4 |

My current thinking is that I leverage a nested dictionary such as the one below. If you agree, how would you go about creating such a dictionary. If not, what would you do?

```
dict = {"A" : {"val 1": "val 3", "val 2" : "val 4"}
        "B" : {"val 1": "val 3", "val 2" : "val 4"}    
}
```

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over your columns from `df1` and merge it individually with a filter on `df2['C']`:

```
for x in df1.columns:
    temp = df1.merge(df2[df2['C'] == x], left_on=x, right_on='D').drop(['C','D'], axis=1)
    df[f'{x}1'] = temp['E']
```

Result:

```
    A       B       A1      B1
0   val 1   val 1   val 3   val 3
1   val 2   val 2   val 4   val 4
```